# Apache Solr Update if exists

Tags: java, apache, solr

I've got the following question issue and question:
As far as I know in Apache Solr an update is basically an delete ( if the entry exists ) followed by an Add. 
My question is: is it somehow possible for Solr to only perform the add operation if the document exists, without using code to check ( some configuration maybe )
I'm using Java and SolrJ to work with Solr ( Version 3.6.1 ).

Edit: some more info about my infrastructure:

I've got a dedicated Thread that executes SolrServer.commit() operations since I'm indexing a lot of documents per seconds ( and also deleting / updating ) - some documents are also linked between them via a field "linked_documents". So basically if I'd need to check if the documents exists before updating I'd have to wait for a commit to happen ( which is very unfeasible ).

Comment: You can check the overwrite attribute @ http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#Optional_attributes_for_.22add.22